# Unable to add border to element on web page

Tags: html, css

I am experimenting with the `float` property of css.

I have tried to codes the match the height of two floating divs.

The two codes

**Method 1.**

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="background: blue;float: left;width: 65%;padding-bottom: 500px;
       margin-bottom: -500px;border:1px solid White;">column a<br />column a</div>
    <div style="background: red;float: right;width: 35%;
      padding-bottom: 500px;margin-bottom: -500px;border:1px solid White;">column b</div>
</div>
```

**Method 2.**

```
<div style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div style="float: left;width: 65%; border:1px solid White;">column a</div>
    <div style="float: right;width: 35%;border:1px solid White;">column b</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Both of the codes works but I want to create border across columns.I applied border property but it didn't work.Is there a solution to above code to add border and be compatible with all browsers.

**Edited Code**

**Method 3.**

```
<div style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div style="float: left;width: 65%; border-right:1px solid White;">
        column acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn 
        acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn 
        acolumn   acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn acolumn 
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;width: 35%;border-right:1px solid White;">column b</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

[Please see the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NcgFf/4/)

The **div with column b** is not showing border of full length

In **Method 1** I am unable to apply border.
Can anyone provide fix for both the issues.

Comment: Where did you apply the border and where do you want it?

Comment: Question not asked properly, reframe it and make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create another div inside your columnA and columnB, with width to 100% and borders.

If you add borders directly to your column div, 35% + 2px is more than 35%, so your total with will be larger than 100%.

Comment: can you explain how it is 2 px,I have added border of 1px;

Comment: It's 1px either side, so 2px added to the width - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/NcgFf/2/

Comment: nice example but I have edited the code please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NcgFf/4/

Answer (score 1):

This may be the solution:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;position: absolute;right: 5px;left: 5px;">
   <div style="background: blue; float: left;width: 65%; border: 1px solid #ccc;">column a</div>
   <div style="background: red; border: 1px solid #ccc;">column b</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should just work:

```
border: 2px solid red;
```

What is the error that you get???